# Regex for checking two words within 6 word limit when second word is a number greater then 20

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will check for a word then a number greater then 20 within 6 words of each other.

I think this should work but I appear to be missing something, anyone able to give me a pointer ?

```
\b(?:word1\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}[2-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}word1)\b
```

This is for a custom classifer within a python driven software engine.

Comment: Your regex looks all right to me, as long as, by "a number greater than 20" you meant "a two-digit number greater than or equal to 20"

Comment: You may be trying to do too much with regular expressions. It would be much more idiomatic to match word-number within 6 words, and then check if the number is greater than 20 using python. Better yet, just use a regex to separate the text into words, and do the rest in plain python. It's much more readable that way.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, unfortunatly the system is only python driven and not a fully usable python installation.  All I've got to work with is the regex option.  At least I know now I'm on the right track, maybe if I split the test in to two seperate checks.  :)

Answer (score -4):

The following regex will find a group of 1-6 words followed by any integer greater than 20:

```
(\w+\s){1,6}([1-9][0-9]{2,}|[2-9][0-9])
```

Alternatively, the following will insist that the number is within 6 words of the *first word in the string* (not entirely clear which you are after):

```
^(\w+\s){1,6}([1-9][0-9]{2,}|[2-9][0-9])
```

Comment: @Downvoters. Please give a reason for your downvotes. Downvoting without commenting is not helpful at all.

Comment: Particularly when the answer appears to meet the specification exactly, unless I have grossly misinterpreted something. It seems downvoting is contagious.

Comment: Regex for checking **two words** within 6 **word** limit

Comment: @AntP well that is what op has asked!

Comment: @Anirudh Yes. Two words, which are within 6 words of each other, where the first is alphabetic and the second is a number greater than 20. Precisely as above. Do not downvote others because you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: answer looks correct. I don't understand the complaints either.